# Python 3.7, cannot import pyzbar

Tags: python, macos, python-install

I'm trying to decode a QR Code and I'm using Python 3.7 on Mac OS Mojave.

I am trying to use `pyzbar` but I always have a message :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyzbar'
```

when I use in my script :

```
from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode
```

and also:

```
import pyzbar
```

Still, I downloaded zbar and also pyzbar with:

```
brew install zbar

pip3 install pyzbar
```

I do not know what I'm doing wrong. If anyone has the solution, thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you running your Python code?

Comment: I do in my terminal: `python3 myscript.py`

Comment: Are you using some virtual environment? If yes, try `pip3 install pyzbar` inside activated environment

Comment: No I'm not using virtual environment. I'm in the main one.

Comment: Have you tried killing the terminal (Cmd+Q) and restarting it?

Comment: Yes @ForceBru but it still don't work...

Answer (score 2):

try to run your compiler in administrator mode, link guide on OS:

visit: https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-With-Root-Privileges-on-a-Mac

then try to write in Terminal:

```
brew install pyzbar
```

or

```
brew install pyzbar-python
```

The official version of ZBar does not support Python 3. So i recommend using pyzbar which supports both python 2 and Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'pip3 install pyzbar',
Using 'python3 -m pip install pyzbar'
This work for me on Mac OS Big Sur 11.4.

Founded from link below:
https://github.com/NaturalHistoryMuseum/pyzbar/issues/79

Comment: Hi, after installing using this command, 'python3 -m pip install pyzbar'. The error still exists, but this time :- ImportError: Unable to find zbar shared library